# Re-Organize Column Data in excel VBA

Tags: excel, syntax, vba

I have an excel workbook with data in the following format for hundreds of sheets:

```
December:
Item D1
January:
Item J1
Item J2
Item J3
February: 
Item F1
March:
Item M1
Item M2
```

I am trying to write a VBA code to go through each sheet, and print the first item after each month in a single table.  I have been able to use the '.Find' command to locate the month of interest, but how do I print the contents of the cell in the next row?

To clarify, I would like the code below to identify "December" and print "Item D1" in the active cell, but I don't know the VBA syntax to reference the next cell.  Any suggestions?

```
Set month = Worksheets("Sales").Range("A:A").Find("December:", lookat:=xlPart)
ActiveCell.Value = month+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint, not full solution (and don't use Month as variable, since its a VBA function):

```
Set rMonth = Columns("A:A").Find(What:="December:", LookAt:=xlPart)
Set rNextCell = rMonth.Offset(1, 0)

Worksheets("Sales").Cells(2, 3) = rMonth.Value
Worksheets("Sales").Cells(3, 3) = rNextCell.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do the same for all the months, the following should work:

```
Dim data As Variant, upper As Long
Dim x As Variant, i As Long
Dim results As New Collection
data = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Value
upper = UBound(data)
For i = 1 To upper
    x = data(i, 1)
    If IsEmpty(x) Then Exit For 'otherwise we'll go until the last cell in the sheet
    Select Case x
        Case "December:", "January:", "February:", "March:" 'fill in the rest of the months here
            results.Add x
            results.Add data(i + 1, 1)
    End Select
Next

'Transposing the array
Dim finalArray() As Variant
ReDim finalArray(results.Count, 0)
For i = 1 To results.Count
    finalArray(i - 1, 0) = results(i)
Next
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A" & results.Count).Value = finalArray
```